# Include foreign framework (no Pod) to own Pod framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I develop a Swift framework, let's name it `MyAwesomeSwiftFramework`, and that framework will be included as a CocoaPod in an other iOS app project. So I define a `podspec` for my framework, include my `MyAwesomeSwiftFramework` as dependency in the Podfile of the app project, install it via `pod install`. Works fine.

Then I have in the `MyAwesomeSwiftFramework` project third party frameworks included, that are no CocoaPods, let's name the first `ForeignSDK.framework`. They all have an entry at `Target/General/Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

```swift
include ForeignSDK

class MyAwesomeSwiftFrameworkClass {

 // access to ForeignSDK works fine
}
```

But when I `pod install` `MyAwesomeSwiftFramework` to the app project, and include it

```swift
include MyAwesomeSwiftFramework
```

I get an error, `ForeignSDK` is missing in the `Pods/MyAwesomeSwiftFramework` of the app project.

> No such module 'ForeignSDK'

```swift
include ForeignSDK // <= No such module 'ForeignSDK' error

class MyAwesomeSwiftFrameworkClass {
}
```

How I have to embed the foreign frameworks to my own framework pod in Xcode, so they are still available when I use my own framework pod in the app project?

I thought something like `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases`, but that doesn't work, when I add there the foreign framework files.